# Find the number of elements greater than x in a given range

Tags: algorithm

Given an array with n elements, how to find the number of elements greater than or equal to a given value (x) in the given range index i to index j in O(log n) complexity?

The queries are of the form (i, j, x) which means find number of elements greater than x from the ith till jth element in the array

The array is not sorted. i, j & x are different for different queries. Elements of the array are static.
Edit: i, j, x all can be different for different queries!

Comment: tried Segment trees?

Comment: any restriction on the range of elements (e.g. 1 <= x <= 100) ?

Comment: Do we know all the queries before hand?

Comment: Is your array sorted?

Comment: I am afraid, that is impossible unless the array is sorted.

Comment: Segment tree / binary indexed tree (fenwick tree) is your friend

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If we know all queries before hand, we can solve this problem by making use of [Fenwick tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree).

First, we need to sort all elements in array and queries together, based on their values.

So, assuming that we have array [5, 4, 2, 1, 3] and queries (0, 1, 6) and (2, 5, 2), we will have following result after sorting : [1, 2, 2, 3 , 4 , 5, 6]

Now, we will need to process each element in descending order:

- If we encounter an element which is from the array, we will update its index in the Fenwick tree, which take O(log n)
- If we encounter a queries, we need to check, in this range of the query, how many elements have been added in the tree, which take O(log n).

For above example, the process will be:

```
  1st element is a query for value 6, as Fenwick tree is empty -> result is 0
  2nd is element 5 -> add index 0 into Fenwick tree
  3rd element is 4 -> add index 1 into tree.
  4th element is 3 -> add index 4 into tree.
  5th element is 2 -> add index 2 into tree.
  6th element is query for range (2, 5), we query the tree and get answer 2.
  7th element is 1 -> add index 3 into tree. 
  Finish.
```

So, in total, the time complexity for our solution is O((m + n) log(m + n)) with m and n is the number of queries and number of element from input array respectively.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the Fenwick tree part? Fenwick tree usually stores a property of a subarray in it. In this case, when you say add index 0 into fenwick tree, you mean that you are doing an update(0, 1) [add 1 to the 0th index of the fenwick tree] ? Assuming this is what you mean, whenever we come to a query (i, j, x), we can be sure that all elements only greater than the query are already pushed into the fenwick tree (because of descending order processing) so we can query fenwick( j ) - fenwick( i ) that will return the number of elements within this range?

Comment: My understanding from your answer is, We put the queries in the array and sort and do a scan from right to left and we maintain a fenwick tree that stores the number of elements seen so far [ a query on fenwick tree query(i) would return the number of elements between 0-i that have been added to the fenwick tree so far] Whenever we come across a query (i, j, x) we know that fenwick tree has only counted elements >= x, so we simply query the tree for query(i, j). Is this what you intended to say? Thanks!!

Comment: @harunrashid Your understanding looks correct to me :)

Answer (score 1):

That is possible only if you got the array sorted. In that case binary search the smallest value passing your condition and compute the count simply by sub-dividing your index range by its found position to two intervals. Then just compute the length of the interval passing your condition.

If array is not sorted and you need to preserve its order you can use index sort . When put together:

1. **definitions**

   Let `<i0,i1>` be your used index range and `x` be your value.
2. **index sort array part `<i0,i1>`**

   so create array of size `m=i1-i0+1` and index sort it. This task is `O(m.log(m))` where `m<=n`.
3. **binary search `x` position in index array**

   This task is `O(log(m))` and you want the index `j = <0,m)` for which `array[index[j]]<=x` is the smallest value `<=x`
4. **compute count**

   Simply count how many indexes are after `j` up to `m`

   ```
    count = m-j;
   ```

As you can see if array is sorted you got `O(log(m))` complexity but if it is not then you need to sort `O(m.log(m))` which is worse than naive approach `O(m)` which should be used only if the array is changing often and cant be sorted directly.

**[Edit1] What I mean by Index sort**

By index sort I mean this: Let have array `a`

```cpp
a[] = { 4,6,2,9,6,3,5,1 }
```

The index sort means that you create new array `ix` of indexes in sorted order so for example ascending index sort means:

```cpp
a[ix[i]]<=a[ix[i+1]]
```

In our example index bubble sort is is like this:

```cpp
// init indexes
a[ix[i]]= { 4,6,2,9,6,3,5,1 }
ix[]    = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 }
// bubble sort 1st iteration
a[ix[i]]= { 4,2,6,6,3,5,1,9 }
ix[]    = { 0,2,1,4,5,6,7,3 }
// bubble sort 2nd iteration
a[ix[i]]= { 2,4,6,3,5,1,6,9 }
ix[]    = { 2,0,1,5,6,7,4,3 }
// bubble sort 3th iteration
a[ix[i]]= { 2,4,3,5,1,6,6,9 }
ix[]    = { 2,0,5,6,7,1,4,3 }
// bubble sort 4th iteration
a[ix[i]]= { 2,3,4,1,5,6,6,9 }
ix[]    = { 2,5,0,7,6,1,4,3 }
// bubble sort 5th iteration
a[ix[i]]= { 2,3,1,4,5,6,6,9 }
ix[]    = { 2,5,7,0,6,1,4,3 }
// bubble sort 6th iteration
a[ix[i]]= { 2,1,3,4,5,6,6,9 }
ix[]    = { 2,7,5,0,6,1,4,3 }
// bubble sort 7th iteration
a[ix[i]]= { 1,2,3,4,5,6,6,9 }
ix[]    = { 7,2,5,0,6,1,4,3 }
```

So the result of ascending index sort is this:

```cpp
//      ix: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
a[]     = { 4,6,2,9,6,3,5,1 }
ix[]    = { 7,2,5,0,6,1,4,3 }
```

Original array stays unchanged only the index array is changed. Items `a[ix[i]]` where `i=0,1,2,3...` are sorted ascending.

So now if `x=4` on this interval you need to find (bin search) which `i` has the smallest but still `a[ix[i]]>=x`  so:

```cpp
//      ix: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
a[]     = { 4,6,2,9,6,3,5,1 }
ix[]    = { 7,2,5,0,6,1,4,3 }
a[ix[i]]= { 1,2,3,4,5,6,6,9 }
//                *
i = 3; m=8; count = m-i = 8-3 = 5;
```

So the answer is `5` items are `>=4`

**[Edit2] Just to be sure you know what binary search means for this**

```cpp
i=0;  // init value marked by `*`
j=4;  // max power of 2 < m , i+j is marked by `^`
//      ix: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7    i j i+j a[ix[i+j]]
a[ix[i]]= { 1,2,3,4,5,6,6,9 }  0 4  4  5>=4          j>>=1;
            *       ^            
a[ix[i]]= { 1,2,3,4,5,6,6,9 }  0 2  2  3< 4 -> i+=j; j>>=1;
            *   ^                  
a[ix[i]]= { 1,2,3,4,5,6,6,9 }  2 1  3  4>=4          j>>=1;
                * ^                  
a[ix[i]]= { 1,2,3,4,5,6,6,9 }  2 0 -> stop 
                *
a[ix[i]] < x -> a[ix[i+1]] >= x -> i = 2+1 = 3 in O(log(m))
```

so you need index `i` and binary bit mask `j` (powers of 2). At first set `i` with zero and `j` with the biggest power of 2 still smaller then `n` (or in this case `m`). Fro example something like this:

```
i=0; for (j=1;j<=m;j<<=1;); j>>=1;
```

Now in each iteration test if `a[ix[i+j]]` suffice search condition or not. If yes then update `i+=j` else leave it as is. After that go to next bit so `j>>=1` and if `j==0` stop else do iteration again. at the end you found value is `a[ix[i]]` and index is `i` in `log2(m)` iterations which is also the number of bits needed to represent `m-1`.

In the example above I use condition `a[ix[i]]<4` so the found value was biggest number still `<4` in the array. as we needed to also include `4` then I just increment the index once at the end (I could use `<=4`instead but was too lazy to rewrite the whole thing again).

The count of such items is then just number of element in array (or interval) minus the `i`.

Comment: I don't think this will work, because, after sorting, order of indexes will not be proper anymore, so your binary search is not enough to answer how many values are there in the query's range.

Comment: Ah, I see, so you only sort those that are inside the query range, ok, get it.

Comment: That depends on the properties of the array. If it is static then you can index sort it once (the whole thing) and then use just that instead. But index sort requires one index per each array element  which is in some cases not possible for memory reasons but in that case it should be stated in question.

Comment: Yes, my understanding is all `i`, `j` and `x` in queries will vary, but looks like there is nothing from the question can confirm that.

Comment: @Spektre I have a few questions first. By index sort, do you mean sorting the array based on value but storing the index too? Like for an array [10, 5, 3, 7] the index sort would be [<3, 2>, <5, 1>, <7, 3>, <10, 0>] where <a, b> represents a is the value and b is the index? Assuming this is what you meant by index sort, when given a query find #elements >= x from index i to j, index sort the array[ i ... j ] and binary search the floor of x and the result is j - floor(x) ?

Comment: @harunrashid added **[edit1]** with simple index sort example

Comment: @Spektre Thanks for the wonderful example! Just to be sure, you have index sorted the entire array. For queries like range [5, 10] & x = 10, we have to index sort only the array elements within the range [5, 10]? Also the binary search is a little different from what I usually use. Will the simple left = 0, right = n-1 & mid calculation kind of binary search work here? Thanks!!

Comment: @harunrashid I added **[Edit2]** with description how binary search works. Anyway as I mentioned before this is usable only if your array is not changing during queries and you got many queries on the same intervals (so you can index sort just once or only few times per many queries) and from that just binary search `O(log(n))`. If your task does not belong to this category then use naive `O(n)` approach because if you index sort before each query then you are in `O(n.log(n))` instead of `O(log(n))` which is a lot slower

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer describes an offline solution using Fenwick tree, but this problem could be solved online (and even when doing updates to the array) with slightly worse complexity. I'll describe such a solution using segment tree and AVL tree (any self-balancing BST could do the trick).

First lets see how to solve this problem using segment tree. We'll do this by keeping the actual elements of the array in every node by range that it covers. So for array `A = [9, 4, 5, 6, 1, 3, 2, 8]` we'll have:

```
[9   4   5   6   1   3   2   8] Node 1
[9   4   5   6] [1   3   2   8] Node 2-3
[9   4] [5   6] [1   3] [2   8] Node 4-7
[9] [4] [5] [6] [1] [3] [2] [8] Node 8-15
```

Since height of our segment tree is `log(n)` and at every level we keep n elements, total amount of memory used is `n log(n)`.

Next step is to sort these arrays which looks like this:

```
[1   2   3   4   5   6   8   9] Node 1
[4   5   6   9] [1   2   3   8] Node 2-3
[4   9] [5   6] [1   3] [2   8] Node 4-7
[9] [4] [5] [6] [1] [3] [2] [8] Node 8-15
```

**NOTE:** You first need to build the tree and then sort it to keep the order of elements in original array.

Now we can start our range queries and that works basically the same way as in regular segment tree, except when we find a completely overlapping interval, we then additionally check for number of elements greater than X. This can be done with binary search in log(n) time by finding the index of first element greater than X and subtracting it from number of elements in that interval.

Let's say our query was `(0, 5, 4)`, so we do a segment search on interval `[0, 5]` and end up with arrays: `[4, 5, 6, 9], [1, 3]`. We then do a binary search on these arrays to see number of elements greater than 4 and get 3 (from first array) and 0 (from second) which brings to total of 3 - *our query answer*.

Interval search in segment trees can have up to `log(n)` paths, which means `log(n)` arrays and since we're doing binary search on each of them, brings complexity to `log^2(n)` per query.

Now if we wanted to update the array, since we are using segment trees its impossible to add/remove elements efficiently, but we can replace them. Using AVL trees (or other binary trees that allow replacement and lookup in log(n) time) as nodes and storing the arrays, we can manage this operation in same time complexity (replacement with `log(n)` time).

Answer (score 0):

This is special variant of orthogonal range counting queries in 2D.
Each element `el[i]` is transformed into point on the plane `(i, el[i])`
and the query `(i,j,x)` can be transformed to count all points in the rectangle `[i,j] x [x, +infty]`.

You can use 2D Range Trees (for example: http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/ga/slides5b.pdf) for such type of the queries.

The simple idea is to have a tree that stores points in the leaves
(each leaf contains single point) ordered by X-axis.
Each internal node of the tree contains additional tree that stores all points from the subtree (ordered by Y-axis).
The used space is `O(n logn)`

Simple version could do the counting in `O(log^2 n)` time, but using 
fractional cascading
this could be reduced to `O(log n)`.

There better solution by Chazelle in 1988 (https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/FunctionalDataStructures.pdf)
to `O(n)` preprocessing and `O(log n)` query time.

You can find some solutions with better query time, but they are way more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to give you a simple approach.

You must have studied merge sort.
In merge sort we keep on dividing array into sub array and then build it up back but we dont store the sorted subarrays in this approach we store them as nodes of binary tree.

this takes up nlogn space and nlogn time to build up;
now for each query you just have to find the subarray this will be done in logn on average and logn^2 in worst case.

These tree are also known as fenwick trees.
If you want a simple code I can provide you with that.